# Can I combine of submit ($_POST processing) and onClick (generate new element)?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have a problem that I want to get the value of pressed button (which generates new input fields everytime it's clicked), and I don't know if I am able to do this..

I have this JS code:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
function addInput(divName){
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = \"<select name=idp[]>$options</select>;
</script>
```

and this php code with html button type

```
$t_prod = "";
$types = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id_type, name_type FROM type_prod ORDER BY id_type");
while ($t = mysqli_fetch_assoc($types)) {
   $t_prod .= "<button type='button' name='typ' value='".$t['id_type']."' onclick=\"addInput('dynamicInput');\">ADD ".$t['name_type']." </button>";              
}
```

and the PHP code generates me four buttons, and I'd like to know which button was pressed (optimally by the id_type) – so the "special" generated content for each button would be generated. But I can't get the value.. I was thinking of some getting of ($_POST['typ']) and calling the function addInput in it according to the number of button pressed.

Comment: Give each button a different `name=`.

Comment: @ceejayoz: OK, but how can I read it? When I have onClick function and isset($_POST['typ']) at the same time, the application "crashes" because it doesn't know either to go via onClick or via isset($_POST['typ']) :( When it enters the JS function, I think, the ($_POST from it - if it was even sent) is lost..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it can be solved client side, just use `this` pointer:

```
<button ... value="btn1" onclick="addInput(this)">
<button ... value="btn2" onclick="addInput(this)">
```

then you can access it in your handler, i.e.:

```
function addInput(obj) {
    if(obj.value=="btn1") // generate your innerHTML for the first button clicked
}
```

the `obj` is the element which was clicked